# Error in Consuming Web Api Post using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I have a  WEB API in MVC, 
i am trying to consume the same in jquery using Ajax

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            contentType: "application/javascript",
            data: data,
            async: false,
            url: "http://localhost:5133/api/Budget_Tracking",
            success: function (jsonData) {
                console.log(jsonData);
            },
            error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(request.responseText);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

I am  getting  error while executing this code ::
error is

```
"jQuery1102043945081951096654_1388391275993 was not called"
```

Comment: `http://localhost:5133/api/Budget_Tracking` are you getting `json` from here? does the server have been configured to send json using `cors`.

Comment: yes it is sending  JSON

Comment: `contentType: "application/javascript",` try removing this. or change to this `contentType: "application/json",`

Comment: tried this also :: not working

Answer (score 0):

Add an `option` to `$.ajax()`

```
jsonpCallback: 'myCallback',
```

Also change `url:` to  `"http://localhost:5133/api/Budget_Tracking?callback=?",`

And create a `function` like,

```
function myCallback(){
   //your code with callback
}
```